# Send As Distribution Group Email Address?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, email, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs

We have a Small Business Server 2003, with a support distribution group.  Is it possible to allow members of a distribution group, send emails from the group email address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to grant the users the "**Send As**" permissions. Not sure how to accomplish that on SBS 2003, but on Exchange 2003 you will:

1. Start the Exchange version of Active Directory Users and Computers
2. From the View menu choose **Advanced Features**.
3. Right click the user who wants to let other people send messages on his behalf and select **Properties**.
4. Select the **Security** tab and click **Advanced**.
5. Select the **Permissions** tab and click **Add**.
6. Enter the users who require the Send As permission, then click **OK**.
7. You will see the list of permissions. Make sure that "*This object only*" is selected for the apply field, then scroll to the bottom and select the *Send As* permission. Click **OK**.
8. **OK** the Advanced security dialog box, and **OK** the User Properties window to close.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Active Directory Users & Computers
- Activate "Advanced Features" in the View menu
- Find the distribution list you want to send as
- Open the properties and go to the Security tab
- Add the user or group in question
- Check the "Send As" permission
- OK your way out

There is by the way a difference between "Send As" and "Send on Behalf Of". In the latter you can see which mailbox did actually send the mail, with "Send As" - and the above procedure - the message appears to come directly from the user that you granted access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You just enter the name of the list in the From: field in a new message.

Comment: Tried using the From: field, but I get "You do not have permission to send to this recipient" email from the server.