# How To Send Email to Active Directory Group?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, email-server

Salvete!  I have two servers, one hosts my email server (hMailServer on windows server 2003) and the other hosts active directory (on windows server 2008).  I don't have Microsoft Exchange.

In Active directory, there are user groups that have email addresses.

*How can I send an email to a user group?*

Somewhere I need to be able to connect my mail server to active directory.  Maybe AD has a mail pickup folder?  I can't find the information that I need.

Here is a similar link, but it didn't help me.
[Send As Distribution Group Email Address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1618/send-as-distribution-group-email-address)

(I think a tag for [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com) would be a good idea.)
Thanks for y'all's help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to find out if hMailServer supports reading AD for distribution groups.  This is typically not a function of AD but rather of the mail server itself.

If it doesn't take a look at Windows Small Business Server, it might limit you in other ways but you do get a copy of MS Exchange which can certainly do this for you.

Comment: A quick search through the hMail documentation doesn't seem to indicate that it supports AD or LDAP. This was only a quick look and a call to their support would be required to be sure. If it does not support reading from AD/LDAP, you will need to maintain two separate directories

Comment: My questiion didn't necessitate that the business had to be done with hMailServer.  I am using hMailServer, but it allows scripting via VBS - and so there may yet be a way to accomplish it.